# Need help getting started using the Google Maps API v3 in Javascript from Actionscript 3

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Could someone please point me to a tutorial that explains how to use Google Maps API v3 in Javascript from Actionscript 3? I'm trying to teach myself, but having no luck so far.  The following test program displays simple HTML but not a Google Map.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- aircomponents/src/HTMLSimple.mxml -->
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
<s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout/>
</s:layout>

<mx:ControlBar width="100%"> 
    <s:Button label="&lt; Back" 
              click="content.historyBack();"/> 
    <s:Button label="Forward &gt;" 
              click="content.historyForward();"/> 
    <s:TextInput id="address" 
                 text="{content.location}" width="100%"/> 
    <s:Button label="Go!" 
              click="content.location = address.text"/> 
</mx:ControlBar> 
<s:Group width="100%" height="100%"> 
    <mx:HTML id="content" location="file:///C:/googlemaps.html"/> 
</s:Group>  
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

The file C:/googlemaps.html works from Firefox and contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDfNNCCL7xmvk-gTYmvS_Cy5PZcf5L3j_I&sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(41., -96),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Forget the "from Actionscript 3" part and start with the documentation. Then let us know if you run into a *specific* problem. Documentation here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

Comment: Thanks @Marcelo.  The javascript/html works fine in the browser, but I need to integrate a map into an existing Actionscript 3 program running under Adobe Air.  <https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/flash/>.  Google Maps API for Flash - (Deprecated)

Note: The Google Maps API for Flash has been officially deprecated as of September 2, 2011. The API will continue to work until September 2, 2014. We encourage you to migrate your code to version 3 of the Maps JavaScript API.

Answer (score 1):

Just this Library for craete a Google Maps with AS3

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-as3/

Answer (score 0):

Set the sizes correctly. If you use percentages your `<body>` element needs a width, so

```
 html,body { height: 100%; width:100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map_canvas { height: 100%; width:100%}
```

And luckily, there is no need to load Flash. :-)
So you can remove

```
s:WindowedApplication ... etc
```

and all the

```
<mx>
```

junk :-)

Comment: Thanks @Marcelo. The javascript/html works fine in the browser, but I need to integrate a map into an existing Actionscript 3 program running under Adobe Air. <developers.google.com/maps/documentation/flash/>;. Google Maps API for Flash - (Deprecated) Note: The Google Maps API for Flash has been officially deprecated as of September 2, 2011. The API will continue to work until September 2, 2014. We encourage you to migrate your code to version 3 of the Maps JavaScript API.